# Why do we only see VIBGYOR colours from dispersion?

Tags: visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, vision, dispersion, perception

I read all the suggested duplicates and they seem to be addressing the relation between primary colours and VIBGYOR. But my straightforward question is when so many colours with different wavelengths exist, why only 7 are special. And secondly when we say that Newton showed white light is made of 7 colours, what does it mean? Is it like some kind of interface of waves or purely biological (like primary colours)? I think its biological because besides prism, we can also prove by a rotating disc in which case wave manipulating seems absurd to me (with minimal knowledge). Am I right?

Comment: Not physics, but reading Wittgenstein might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Newton thought seven is a beautiful number (the seven sins, the seven wonders of the world, the seven plagues of Egypt, seven days of the week, seven angles). He basically picked indigo as a separate color because otherwise there would be only six colors and that "wouldn't be right".

You could just as well add cyan (blue/green) as a distinguishable color and you have eight colors.

It ultimately boils down to how the human eye works [three primary colors (RGB) and three mix colors (CMY)], where magenta does not exist as a spectral color becaus it is a mixture of the long- and short end of the spectrum. Due to the overlapping spectra of the red and blue receptors in the retina, violet has a bit of the characteristic of purple, so six fundamental colors (violet, B, C, G, Y, R) is biologically defensible. The in-between colors such as indigo and orange are a matter of training and convention.

Comment: I'm quite satisfied with the answer. Thanks! But I have a doubt.** I keep primary colours as standard for white light. Because all primary colours are already found in the Newtonian spectrum, so can we conclude that  all the remaining colours also form white light by means of some addition and subtraction?? **And by the way it is so awe inspiring that 7 is an arbitrary number.. Models and assumptions are so important for physics! and even random numbers can make perfect sense when put in the right order.

Comment: You can post the first part of your comment as a new question. About the number 7: give Mr. Newton a break! :-) The world was a different place in 1700. Newton basically invented modern physics and a lot of the high-school math as well.

Answer (score 1):

The colours on the spectrum are special because each one represents a frequency of light. Other colours can only be made as combinations of the spectral colours. Our eyes (according to standard theory) perceive 3 colours; this is because the cone cells in most of our retinas have 3 different chemicals in them.

Comment: But that basically was my question.. Why are the frequencies of only 7 colours special when 3 colours are good enough to make white light (I know newton didn't know it that way back then.)

Comment: Our eye can see little difference between yellow light and a particular mixture of red light and green light. I have seen street lights that looked white, but made some coloured cars look black. Physics does not have the number 7 - this is a human construction. The biology has 3. We can see colours that cannot be made up from the standard 3. The take-away message is - Colour vision is complex and wonderful.

Comment: And then there are “impossible” colors: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impossible_color.